# ypcat passwd does not list complete list of users in linux

Tags: linux, nis

We have new environment set up which is a secure chamber, meaning only authorised users can login in and use NX software. The weird issue I’m looking at is that when I do `ypcat passwd`, it gives only a partial list and not complete as it’s giving for normal systems. What could be the issue?

When I invoke `ypcat passwd` it gives the user listing up to the `d` character stating the sequence and stops without issue, though when I check `ypcate <user_name> passwd` it works, meaning names are in database and are returning; while querying specifically but in single `ypcat passwd` not working.

Comment: What serves your NIS/YP user list? (Windows? Unix/Linux? What flavour?)

Comment: @roaima its Linux based systems basically RedHat or CentOs

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to say "when I check `ypmatch <user_name> passwd` it works".

You didn't really post any details of how your "secure" setup is configured. Deliberately truncating ypcat output could be construed as a useful security feature, hard to say.

Look at `ypwhich` output, ssh to that server, and repeat the `ypcat` experiment, comparing it with the local indexed files being used by `ypserv`. Verify there is adequate free disk space. Edit the source, rebuild the indexed files, and verify that truncation persists.

Comment: thank you for the details , Though, its really meaning `ypcat <username> passwd` not the `ypmatch`. However , about security setup  , i mean to say is that.. we have recently built up a secure chamber where only permiitive people can login into it by puching down he firewall So, an ordinary user can not logon to it and this is bulit for the customers demand to secure their data in a protctive zone apart from the others as we have diffrent customers. but from Unix securirty satndpoint there is no chnage made as such .

Comment: Indeed, this a complain from a user who usulaly using this ypcat data and dumping for some reason outside the secure zone but same not working inside.